# Google street view image exact location

Tags: google-street-view

Google street view API allows you to request the street view image from a certain location, viewpoint and direction the response is the image only. Yet, if the location does not have an image it sometimes returns the closest image existing but does not update you as to where the image was taken from

Example:
The image received from the location (32.78554181114093, 35.01731804123101) is actually taken from (32.7855604,35.0176555).

I wish to receive also the true location at which the image was taken.